# Xlabel is not appearing

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have wrote a simple code to plot bar graph using matplotlib from a dataframe. Code is working properly but the `xlabel` is not appering. Here is the code.

```
def dm2():
    clear()
    axis = [0,1,2,3,4]
    top =df[df.Rating>=4]
    top = top.head()
    plt.bar(axis,top.Rating,width = 0.4) 
    plt.xticks(axis,top.Restaurant_Name, rotation = 45)   
    plt.xlabel("Restaurants")
    plt.ylabel("Rating",fontsize = 12)
    plt.title("Hotel Reviews")
    plt.show()
```

and this is the result

[image: 1]

Comment: The axis x-label should be visible below the x-tick labels (Indian Accent, Baluchi, etc.) — have you tried to zoom out a little or move the plot a little towards the top?

Comment: Add `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()`.